# Как изменить welcome.blade.php через форму в admin panel?

Tags: php, laravel, package

Хочу добавить фичу на свой сайт.

Пример: необходимо добавить рекламный блок в необходимое мне место шаблона. У нас есть шаблон **product.blade.php** по нему выводятся все продукты. Заходим в админ панель, берем наш блок который хотим вставить, берем view который хотим изменить, вставляем нужный блок в нужное место, update. В результате, все продукты теперь будут с рекламным блоком.

**Как такое сделать, возможно уже есть готовые пакеты?**

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать с помощью таблицы в базе данных. Например есть таблица reklama туда вставятся путь к файлу рекламы и идентификатор блока.

id  path                       block_id

1   include.adblock1.blade.php 1

2   include.adblock2.blade.php 2

в нужных видах

```
<?php
$ad=App\Ads::where('block_id',1)->first();//Ads это модель
?>

@section('reklama1')
@include({{$ad->path}})
@endsection

<?php
$ad=App\Ads::where('block_id',2)->first();//Ads это модель
?>

@section('reklama2')
@include({{$ad->path}})
@endsection
```